# GroupBy transformation operator is working only on local environment

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to refactor the code and meanwhile I found a bug which I wanted to understand.
It's working on local environment but not in QA environment.
Data:

```
const dataSet: DataSetInterface[] = [
      { id:57, firstProperty:148, secondProperty:1, thirdProperty:10.30 },
      { id:58, firstProperty:149, secondProperty:4, thirdProperty:20.60 },
      { id:59, firstProperty:148, secondProperty:4, thirdProperty:22.20 }
    ];
```

Old method which is not working:

```
private groupAndSumUp(dataSet: DataSetInterface[]) {
  Rx.Observable.from(dataSet)
      .groupBy(x => x.secondProperty)
      .flatMap(group => group.toArray())
      .map(g => {
        return {
          id: g[0].secondProperty,
          secondProperty: g[0].thirdProperty,
          budgetDays: _.sumBy(g, 'budgetDays'), 
        }
      })
      .toArray()    
      .subscribe(d => this.budgetDays = d); 
}
```

Locally it's working but on QA environment I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: e.map is not a function
```

I have no idea why. Maybe that's because GroupedObservables are not completed before first method toArray() ?

I will try to refactor in but it's not tested yet and before that I want to understand why it's not working correctly in QA.
Example how I want to refactor it:

```
    const example = source.pipe(
      groupBy(x => x.id),
      mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
      map(g => {
        return {
          id: g[0].secondProperty,
          secondProperty: g[0].thirdProperty,
          budgetDays: _.sumBy(g, 'budgetDays'), 
        }
      }),
      toArray()
    );
```

**Update**

I've tried refactored version:

```
private groupAndSumUp(pricingLevels: SingleContractWorkPackagePricingLevel[]) {
  from(pricingLevels).pipe(
    groupBy(x => x.masterAgreementPricingLevelId),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    map(g => {
      return {
        id: g[0].masterAgreementPricingLevelId,
        masterAgreementPricingLevel: g[0].budgetDays,
        budgetDays: _.sumBy(g, 'budgetDays'), 
      }
    }),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe(d => this.budgetDays = d); 
}
```

And now I have and error:
ERROR TypeError: Vn.a.from(...).groupBy is not a function

My imports:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, map, mergeMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Rxjs version:

```
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
```

My error has changes:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined
    at 7-es2015.23db786fc6208d7e819e.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.setSelectedDays (7-es2015.23db786fc6208d7e819e.js:1)
    at t.ngOnChanges (7-es2015.23db786fc6208d7e819e.js:1)
    at t.We (main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1)
    at Ut (main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1)
    at $t (main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1)
    at Vt (main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1)
    at Zi (main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1)
    at main-es2015.1967bf97e6c77b08a1d5.js:1
```

Comment: Likely related to how the app is packaged for running in QA. Can you share more about how you run your code in local vs on QA?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume it's not working, because it can't find the `.map` operator. This happened in the old rxjs way if you didn't use the following import statement:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Now it could be that in the QA environment, the application is optimized and minified and the `map` operator can't be found anymore. This can happen if you haven't visited a certain page yet (which does include that import). To "fix" it, you need to put that import in the file where you actually use the map operator.

However, your refactor is obviously the appropriate fix.

Comment: I've just tested in on my DEV environent, I mean my refactored version and now I have a bug: main-es2015.8595b64341733ca9606d.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Vn.a.from(...).groupBy is not a function

Comment: @RobertDaraż doesn't seem like you are using `.pipe`

Comment: sorry, I pasted wrong part of the code. Now is correct

Comment: @RobertDaraż can you show me the imports that you are using, and what rxjs version you have?

Comment: I've just edited post. Currently the error has changed as you can see in updated version of post

Comment: @RobertDaraż so your refactor seems to work now. Rule of thumb though, you only import from `rxjs` or from `rxjs/operators`. You should not import your `Observable` from there. The error you are getting in your code now has nothing to do with the code you posted, as I can't see the `setSelectedDays` function. You should try to see what data that function is receiving, and what you expected it to receive